# How to redirect to another page Reactjs/nextjs sending data with post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How can I send data using post
I got this

```
router.push({
            pathname: "/investigacion-detalle",
            query: { data: JSON.stringify(salida),},
        });
```

but all it's sended on the url, I want to use a redirect post, to send all data and make the redirection, but I don't know how to make that, I try making a fetch but that only give me a response from the page not the redirect

The redirect Page:

```
import React,{useEffect} from "react";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'
const InvestigacionDetalle = (props)=>{
  const router = useRouter()
  const handleURL = (e)=>{
    router.push('/investigacion');
  };
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(props.router.query.data);
  },[])
return(
    <div>
  <div>Investigacion page</div>
  <button onClick={handleURL}>test</button>
  </div>
  );
}
export default withRouter(InvestigacionDetalle);
```

Comment: Where do you want to POST the data to?